# Execute shellscript on linked container after mysql Import is done

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile I am using these two lines to copy 3 mysql dumps in the entry Folder and the execute a shellscript:

```
ADD dumps /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY echo.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/9echo.sh
```

This works fine, but I am looking for a way to now call a shellscript in the linked PHP Container

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    build: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: app
      MYSQL_USER: app
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
    expose:
      - 3360
    networks:
      - traefik_traefik
    restart: ${RESTART}
  php73:
    build:
      context: ./php
      args:
        feature_tag: ${CONTAINER_PREFIX}
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - traefik_traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_php73.rule=Host(${URLS})"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.thisauth.basicauth.users=swiss:$$apr1$$nb9MT1Rk$$swy9fdsfcz8YFXYdzwBwR1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_php73.middlewares=thisauth@docker"
```

Because I can only call this script when the DB is fully loaded with the needed data. Otherwise the PHP Code will not work.

Is there a after init Script Call I can use in docker-compose oder the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is what you meant, but if you want to call a shell script
after DB and php is up you can change docker-compose.yml like this :

```
  php73:
    build:
      context: ./php
      args:
        feature_tag: ${CONTAINER_PREFIX}
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - traefik_traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_php73.rule=Host(${URLS})"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.thisauth.basicauth.users=swiss:$$apr1$$nb9MT1Rk$$swy9fdsfcz8YFXYdzwBwR1"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${CONTAINER_PREFIX}_php73.middlewares=thisauth@docker"
    command: sh -c ' bash script.sh'
```